# Is Steam just a store, or do game servers run through it as well?

Tags: steam

Say I buy something like Fifa or Rainbow Six Siege. What do they base their Multiplayer off of? Do they have their own servers from their end or is everything run through Steam as the platform and server?

Comment: They all still have their own servers. Steam just provides a platform and eventually Steam friends and achievements support. Some games require a Steam account, since the game can only be bought or activated on Steam, but the majority of games does not (FIFA requires an EA account for example).

Comment: You need to be a bit more specific here. There are tons of online platforms that don't require Steam and some that do.

Comment: That edit changes far too much of the asker's intent. It should not have been done, @n_palum.

Comment: @Frank Feel free to roll it back then, I wasn't sure if it was changing *too* much. I figured this was more of what the OP was trying to get at, and the formulation of the question wasn't great originally. I don't feel it was or is too broad, as the current answer (IMO) answers it.

Answer (score 5):

Steam is just a store, another place where you can buy a game from.

You can buy Rainbow Six from [Steam](http://store.steampowered.com/app/359550/Tom_Clancys_Rainbow_Six_Siege/) and play it trough it, but you can just as easily buy it [from Amazon as a Physical Disc](https://www.amazon.co.uk/d/Shops/UBI-Soft-300076410-Tom-Clancys-Rainbow-Siege/B00KJGJLG4?th=1) you'd get trough the mail [or as a download code for uPlay](https://www.amazon.co.uk/d/Shops/UBI-Soft-300076410-Tom-Clancys-Rainbow-Siege/B01MQKK927?th=1) - (the Ubisoft version of Steam, but just for their games). You'll still play online on Ubisoft's servers.

Steam's Valve as a game development company has multiplayer servers on which you play the games made by Valve. Think Counter Strike GO an Portal Co-Op.

Comment: Thanks - so when you register an account to play online is it through a ubisoft account in the case of any ubisoft game?

Comment: @TristanAtPlayer-Three I own Rainbow Six Siege through Steam, and launch it there, but in the game it's all Ubisoft and uPlay. I'm logged in to my uPlay account when I'm playing and it's entirely their servers.

Comment: Steam is more than just a store, it is also a content distribution platform, has aspects of a social network (chat, friends, feed, ...), cloud storage for save games, achievement tracking, matchmaking ...